# Como inserir a classe active dependendo da página que o usuário está?

Tags: php, nav-bar

Tenho esse código:

```
function showNavbar(){
    echo "<ul class='nav nav-list'>
    <li class='active'>
        <a href='index.php'>
            <i class='menu-icon fa fa-tachometer'></i>
            <span class='menu-text'> Painel </span>
        </a>

        <b class='arrow'></b>
    </li>";

    if(empty($_SESSION['tipo'])):
        echo "<li class=''>
    <a href='#'>
        <i class='menu-icon fa fa-desktop'></i>
        <span class='menu-text'> Escritório Virtual </span>
    </a>

    <b class='arrow'></b>
</li>";else: 
echo "<li class=''>
<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>
    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-desktop'></i>
    <span class='menu-text'>
        Escritório Virtual
    </span>

    <b class='arrow fa fa-angle-down'></b>
</a>

<b class='arrow'></b>

<ul class='submenu'>
    <li class=''>
        <a href='lista.php'>
            <i class='menu-icon fa fa-caret-right'></i>
            Empresas
        </a>

        <b class='arrow'></b>
    </li>
</ul>
</li>";endif;
echo "
<li class=''>
    <a href='lista2.php'>
        <i class='menu-icon fa fa-barcode'></i>
        <span class='menu-text'> Boletos</span>
    </a>

    <b class='arrow'></b>
</li>

<li class=''>
    <a href='lista3' class='dropdown-toggle'>
        <i class='menu-icon fa fa-calculator'></i>
        <span class='menu-text'> Notas Fiscais </span>

        <b class='arrow fa fa-angle-down'></b>
    </a>
</li>           
</ul>";
}
```

#### O que ele faz:

Ele monta toda a barra de navegação lateral. Fiz em uma função para não ter que ficar repetindo toda vez e ajudar na hora da manutenção.

### Meu Problema

Conforme vocês podem ver a 1ª `<li>` está com a classe *active*, que demonstra que essa é a página que o usuário está, dando um pequeno destaque:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que se eu usar o código chamando ele dessa maneira:

```
<?php showNavbar(); ?>
```

Somente a 1ª `<li>` que é a do index vai ficar com a classe *active*, **sempre**. Como eu posso fazer com que pegue o nome da página e então coloque a classe *active* na página correta e não sempre na 1ª?

Answer (score 0):

Coloca um `id` na `ul` principal do menu e também coloca um `id` em cada item.

Quando você chamar sua função para imprimir o menu passa o `id` que você quer ativar naquela página, por exemplo quero que ative o menu Empresas:

```
<?php showNavbar("mnEmpresas"); ?>
```

E no final dessa função adiciona um `script` para ser impresso:

```
function showNavbar($idMenuAtivo){
    echo "
        <ul id='menu' class='nav nav-list'>
            <li id='mnPainel'>
                <a href='index.php'>
                    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-tachometer'></i>
                    <span class='menu-text'> Painel </span>
                </a>
                <b class='arrow'></b>
            </li>
    ";

    if(empty($_SESSION['tipo'])):
        echo "
            <li id='mnEscritorioVirtual'>
                <a href='#'>
                    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-desktop'></i>
                    <span class='menu-text'> Escritório Virtual </span>
                </a>
                <b class='arrow'></b>
            </li>
        ";
    else: 
        echo "
            <li id='mnEscritorioVirtual'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle'>
                    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-desktop'></i>
                    <span class='menu-text'>
                        Escritório Virtual
                    </span>
                    <b class='arrow fa fa-angle-down'></b>
                </a>
                <b class='arrow'></b>
                <ul class='submenu'>
                    <li id='mnEmpresas'>
                        <a href='lista.php'>
                            <i class='menu-icon fa fa-caret-right'></i>
                            Empresas
                        </a>
                        <b class='arrow'></b>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        ";
    endif;
    echo "
            <li id='mnBoletos'>
                <a href='lista2.php'>
                    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-barcode'></i>
                    <span class='menu-text'> Boletos</span>
                </a>
                <b class='arrow'></b>
            </li>
            <li id='mnNotasFiscais'>
                <a href='lista3' class='dropdown-toggle'>
                    <i class='menu-icon fa fa-calculator'></i>
                    <span class='menu-text'> Notas Fiscais </span>
                    <b class='arrow fa fa-angle-down'></b>
                </a>
            </li>           
        </ul>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#menu #<? echo $idMenuAtivo; ?>').addClass('active');
        </script>
    ";
}
```

Comment: Não entendi, poderia me dar um exemplo, por exemplo na página chamda listaUsu.php?

Comment: Editei minha resposta